# Strange Ajax Behaviour

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm making small project, basically CRUD type project on Codeigniter. I'm using Messi Jquery Modal Library, loading controller with Messi.load ajax.

Problem.

```
// Edit Operator
$('.edit_details').on('click', function() {
var edit_id = $(this).attr('id');

$.getScript("<?php echo $this->config->base_url() ?>media/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js");
Messi.load('<?php echo $this->config->base_url() ?>index.php/option/detail/' + edit_id);
$.getScript("<?php echo $this->config->base_url() ?>media/js/validation.js");
});
```

when i load modal box with ajax, i also load jquery library and some jquery function for the modal content, for example validation.js

controller

```
// check operator
public function detail($id)
{
    $this->load->model('Option_Model', 'option');

    $data['result'] = $this->option->checkOperator($id);
    $data['states'] = $this->option->getStates();

    $this->load->view('option', $data);
}
```

everything works perfectly except that ajax loading problem. i almost finished project and suddenly found out, **simetimes jquery does not work properly**.

for example:

when i load one of that Messi modal boxes, i also use $.getscript and load ip.address.js jquery plugin, because I load some view that needs Ip Address validation. sometimes works, sometimes not. I searched everything i could, tried what i could but cannot understand the problem reason, why it works some times, and some times it does not.

I also have many ajax jquery functions in those modal boxes and they work fine, but functions, that load from $.getscript have problems sometimes.

Edited:
here is ip address declaration in my modal box.

```
var ipAddress = (function(){
    $('.ip').ipAddress();
});
ipAddress();
```

**Magic**
first two Attempts did not work, third one worked.

[image]

Comment: The '...is not a function' errors occur because no element of class 'ip' exists when the function is called; the problem, then, is figuring out why that's happening and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scripts are being loaded asynchronously, so you cannot guarantee the order they are loaded.

I'm also confused about why you're loading jquery using a jquery function `$.getScript()`...

But disregarding that, you should load scripts after their dependencies have been loaded:

```
$.getScript('/path/to/dependency', function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    $.getScript('/load/dependant/script/here');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

You should also look at Deferred objects that jQuery has that makes loading several dependencies easy:

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/